# Spring mvc не находит страницу - 404. Решено (вроде бы)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

уже не знаю что делать. Все перепроверил.

Создал проект. подключил спринг. Добавил спринг в артефакт для деплоя (tomcat 9) (Проверял - либы выгружаются).

Настроил `xml`, создал контроллер.

**НО!** спринг ничего не находит. При заходе на главную страницу - 404. что не так? не понимаю.

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!--<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>-->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!--<mvc:annotation-driven />-->

</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.spring.learning.controller"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

BaseController:

```
@Controller
public class BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: При деплое Tomcat9 в IDEA папка pages пустая, хотя в проекте файлы есть

Comment: Пересоздал артефакт - файлы появились. Но все равно не находит, хотя файлы есть.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два решения которые мне помогли.

Первое (как мне кажется не самое лучшее) добавить в `web.xml` такое:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Второе (не знаю как, может после пересоздания артефакта):

В `web.xml` вместо:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

сделать так:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```